# HTML embed not working for Java Applet

Tags: java, html, tomcat, jar, applet

I've been researching on which to use between `<applet>`,`<object>`, or `<embed>`, but none seem to work.

When I tried to load JApplet through HTML I am got RuntimeException error   `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sforce/ws/ConnectionException`.

When I tried to run number1.class with the number1.class being in myfile.jar it needs the other 3 jar files for the library and that is what the error is. The files look like this:

```
tomcat-->webapps-->applet-->newhtml.html
applet-->lib-->(wsc-23,enterprise,partner)
applet-->applet_class-->(number1.class,myfile.jar)
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
I've also looked through majority of stackoverflow questions as well as other places, but still no luck!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <html type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
         width="512" height="512"
         code="applet_class.number1.class"
         src="myfile.jar,applet/lib/wsc-23.jar,
         applet/lib/enterprise.jar,
         applet/lib/partner.jar"/></html>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may need to specify the code base so the applet knows where to find the additional resources...You should also take a look at [Applet Deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html)

Comment: so would codebase be the absolute path to my .jar files?

Comment: No. Java Applets run on the client.  Your jar files have to be in your webroot because if your webserver isn't serving them, how will the user's browser have access to them? Paths should be relative to your webserver root.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, your Applet Deployment link just redirects to a Java Download page.  Thanks alot Oracle.

Comment: @developerwjk Probably because the page is trying to open an applet, start at [Lesson: Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) and look for *"Deploying an Applet"*

Comment: Oh...No matter where you start you can't read this documentation without the Java plugin installed and turned on in the browser.

Comment: The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).

But looking at that element..

```html
  <html type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
     width="512" height="512"
     code="applet_class.number1.class"
     src="myfile.jar,applet/lib/wsc-23.jar,
     applet/lib/enterprise.jar,
     applet/lib/partner.jar"/></html>
```

The most basic form of the applet element (deprecated in HTML 4.01 is):

```html
  <applet 
     width="512" height="512"
     code="applet_class.number1"
     archive="myfile.jar,applet/lib/wsc-23.jar,applet/lib/enterprise.jar,applet/lib/partner.jar"/>
 </applet>
```

- Change `html` to `applet`.
- Remove the `type` attribute.
- Remove the `.class` from the end of the code attribute.
- Change `src` to `archive`, and have all the archives in one line.

Comment: yeah, the html embed was a written mistake into here. I did all that, but still nothing...

Comment: also, with the DTS I just get a gray box now. Better than what it was, but not quite fully functioning.

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: BTW - I edited the answer to change `src` to `archive` as I mentioned in comments..